# How to store binary type data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I have a simple yet for me difficult problem. I am encoding some integer data into binary type in a python script, and now I would like to load this binary data into a mysql table. I'm using pymysql to connect with the mysql database.

I've tried dropping the encoding in python, and leaving it to mysql to load it into a blob file. Here mysql uses a utf-8 encoding, which I'm not interested in. Maybe I can change the way mysql encodes the blob files?

Or better yet, can I just use the encoded data that I already have, and load it into the mysql table directly

Thanks!

Comment: There's a MySQL datatype called [`BIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html)(which you'd need to supply the length for) that can store a string of 0s and 1s for any actual number you input. You don't even have to worry about doing the conversion in a script. Or, if you use `INSERT` statement with a value like `b'0111'`, it'd accept the binary input too.

Comment: I've tried to read the mysql manual on bit, but I don't quite see how the function works. like I want for instance to encode the integer '10' to a 2 byte long binary number

Comment: I don't understand the example. You're showing me that BIT both accept integers and binary numbers? I'm interested in converting a integer number to a binary number, and it would also be nice, if I can select how many bytes to store this integer in

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment was a bit incomplete and hence removed it. I was trying to suggest you to run the set of queries shown [here](http://rextester.com/ISDW32922) on a local installation. For instance, I'm able to see the binary number if I use `BIT` type and input the number in either integer or bit format (preceded by `b`). And because of the fact that it can accept both INT and BIT as direct inputs, you'll just have to be a little careful with the implementation. Certainly, if you give the length of the field as `BIT(16)`, it'll occupy 2 bytes.

Comment: I'm not following. it's really basic. I'm seaching for a function, which takes as an input an integer and outputs the binary encoding of this integer.